# How to put "description" of the field in the form field?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am new to python coding. I am trying to create a form using flask and for one of the form field, want to add the field description, but I am not able to see it.

Please help me out with the help text of the field.

Below is sample PY code:

```
smp = StringField(label = 'Start of MP', description='Valid Format is YYYY-MM-DD', validators=[InputRequired()])
```

HTML code is as below:

```
<div class="form-group">
                 {{ form.smp.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.smp.errors %}
                        {{ form.smp(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.smp.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.smp(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
```

What am I missing here, why description is not showing when I run HTML page?

Comment: Are you trying to add help text or placeholder text? The description parameter confuses a lot of people who are new to WTForms who think it is for placeholder text.

Comment: @KevinWelch  Yeah I am trying to add a placeholder, not the help text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `description` param is used for help text.

You can use `render_kw` to set placeholder text. Pass it a dictionary with a `placeholder` key and your placeholder text.

`smp = StringField(label = 'Start of MP', render_kw={'placeholder': 'Valid Format is YYYY-MM-DD'}, validators=[InputRequired()])`

This only works in WTForms 2.1+ but you can always just put it in your template file.

`{{ form.smp(placeholder="Placeholder Text Here") }}`

Comment: render_kw did the trick for me, though {{ form.smp(placeholder="Placeholder Text Here") }} put the placeholder text besides the label and not in the box/field itself.