# WTForms how to use description paramter

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, werkzeug, wtforms-json

I have some simple boolean field and I want to add a short description.
I specified a `description` parameter but it seems like no effecr.
How it suppose to work at all?

```
from wtforms import BooleanField, Form


class AdminUsersForm(Form):
    foo = BooleanField(label='foo', default=True, description='foo')
```

```
<form method="GET">
    <div>
        {{ form.foo.label }}
        {{ form.foo(placeholder=checkbox.description)}}
        # No description impact at all, even tooltip.
    </div>
</form>
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58105688/11277611) answer but not sure that it's my case

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. Try changing your 'placeholder' to display the text that you have defined:

```
{{ form.foo(placeholder=form.foo.description)}}
```

You access this the same way as the `form.label`, simply by calling the parameter of the field of the form.